# How to open a new browser window on click using jQuery UI dialog box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jquery UI dialog box, and I have some radio buttons and a submit button.

If the 1st button is selected, and the user clicks the button, I want a new window to open just like if there was a href tag like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

So in the click event so far I am at:

```
$(this).click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is it possible to do this? (has to work in IE)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: `window.open` does not work ?

Comment: @Archer it is `w3fools.com`

Comment: @Archer There's lots of misinformation on w3schools, so we avoid referencing it.

Comment: @Barmar Okay - I didn't know it had that reputation.  I don't use it myself.  It was just the first result in google.  I checked it and it looked okay.  Another thing I've learnt today :)

Answer (score 5):

This here should help. Look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pcDbX/

```
$('#link').click(function () {

     window.open('http://www.example.com','mywindow','width=400,height=200')

});
```

Also this link will show you what parameters you can use: 
http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

And here are some common attributes to pass to the `window.open()`:

> 1. width=300 Use this to define the width of the new window.
> 2. height=200 Use this to define the height of the new window.
> 3. resizable=yes or no Use this to control whether or not you want the user to be able to resize the window.
> 4. scrollbars=yes or no This lets you decide whether or not to have scrollbars on the window.
> 5. toolbar=yes or no Whether or not the new window should have the browser navigation bar at the top (The back, foward, stop
>      buttons..etc.).
> 6. location=yes or no Whether or not you wish to show the location box with the current url (The place to type the address).
> 7. directories=yes or no Whether or not the window should show the extra buttons. (what's cool, personal buttons, etc...).
> 8. status=yes or no Whether or not to show the window status bar at the bottom of the window.
> 9. menubar=yes or no Whether or not to show the menus at the top of the window (File, Edit, etc...).
> 10. copyhistory=yes or no Whether or not to copy the old browser window's history list to the new window.

Comment: @user1361315 Sure. Look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pcDbX/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   $('#buttonid').click(function(){

      window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');

   });
```